# how can i disable the options of a video when i right click it (HTML)

Tags: html, css, contextmenu

I just integrated a video in my website and everything is going Ok, I just enabled the autoplay, loop, muted all these attributes but I'm facing a problem when I right click the video I found theses options:

[image]

I googled it but I didn't found anything useful all I found is how I disable the right click on my video which I don't want.
it's not a best practice, please can you help me disable them (the options with the arrow)

sorry if you don't speak french let me translate to you (Repeat, show commands , save video as, PIP mode)

and thaaaaaank you in advance

Comment: use jquery for it

Comment: You can't disable parts of the right-click (context) menu, you can either display it or not

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jquery contextMenu plugin to rebuild your menu and only display the items you want.

1. download the plugin from [github](https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu) and register it in your project
2. Setup the menu and use it as an eventListner

   ```
   $(function() {
   $.contextMenu({
       selector: '.context-menu-one', 
       callback: function(key, options) {
           var m = "clicked: " + key;
           window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
       },
       items: {
           "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
           "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
          copy: {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
           "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
           "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
           "sep1": "---------",
           "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
               return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
           }}
       }
   });

   $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
       console.log('clicked', this);
   })
   ```

   });

Comment: added some additional clarity from the suggested link

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following javascript code to disable right menu

```html
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" id="my-video-player" width="854" height="480" controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soZOr25vK-k" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#videoElementID').bind('contextmenu',function() { return false; });
});
</script>
```